# Interesting problem with VBA error 91, protection and intersetcion

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, set-intersection

Please, could anyone help with error 91, I can't find a solution. Firstly the related code part:

```
.......
Application.EnableEvents = False 
PrUpr.UJournal 'Protection code for sheet is located in  PrUpr module.
Intersect(targetRow, rgRecName) = foundName '!! Here the problem comes out !!
.......
PrUpr.PJournal
.......
```

Where `PrUpr.UJournal` contains many subs including:

```
Sub UJournal()
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Journal").Unprotect "123"
End Sub
```

The protection was activated with the code:

```
Sub PJournal()
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Journal")
   .Protect Password:="123", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, 
    AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=False, 
    AllowFiltering:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
   .EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
 End With
End Sub
```

`targetRow (entire row range), rgRecName(column range) And  foundName(string)`  All contain readable values, however `Intersect(targetRow, rgRecName)` value is nothing.

The code works under the event  `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`, everything works fine until I turn on the protection of the sheet with a macro and then try to unprotect it. No `ActiveSheet` and commands like this is used in the code. The code always works when I use debug mode step by (F8) from the beginning, but when it works automatically it throws an error. `Wait` doesn't help either. If the code starts working with an unprotected sheet, then everything works fine until protection is enabled by code (or manually). `UserInterfaceOnly:=True / False` unfortunately has no effect. `Workbook_Open` doesn't contains protection-related objects Setting the whole sheet cells parameter to locked or unlocked does nothing. Two userforms are open while the code is running.
Maybe someone has faced such a problem?

Comment: Since you've unprotected the sheet before the `Intersect` error it seems unrelated to protection, and due to some other factor we can't see.  Unless your unprotect call failed due to `On Error Resume Next` for example.

Comment: "The code always works when I use debug mode step by (F8) from the beginning, but when it works automatically it throws an error" -- this is very typically a symptom of having [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Index/Inspections?tab=All&page=2&page_size=20#ImplicitActiveSheetReference) and/or [implicit ActiveWorkbook références](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Index/Inspections?tab=All&page=2&page_size=20#ImplicitActiveWorkbookReference), both of which Rubberduck can easily locate anywhere in your project for you

Comment: I suspect rgRecName isn't coming from the expected worksheet when you hit this error, but it's hard to tell because the relevant code isn't being shown.

Comment: The same error 91 on intersect, but reason was in missing "set" before the result assignment to Range variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a bit to unpack here:

```
Intersect(targetRow, rgRecName) = foundName
```

Intersect will return a `Range` object representing the cells that intersect between the two provided ranges; if no cell intersects, that's when you get `Nothing`.

Now that's on the LHS of a value assignment, so what VBA is trying to do here is to let-coerce the RHS value into the LHS object, and it can only do this by invoking that object's *default member* - but if there is no object reference, then the member call against `Nothing` does what it does every time: it raises run-time error 91.

So you're getting error 91 because `rgRecName` isn't intersecting with `TargetRow`.

Typically you would use the result of `Intersect` together with `Is Nothing` as part of a conditional where you run some code when there's an intersection - since the intersection of a row with a column is necessarily a single cell the assignment is safe, but still declare and set a variable to avoid doing the work twice:

```
Dim intersection As Range
Set intersection = Intersect(targetRow, rgRecName)
If Not intersection Is Nothing Then
    intersection.Value = foundName
Else
    Debug.Print rgRecName.Address & " does not intersect " & targetRow.Address
End If
```

Look into why the intersection is `Nothing` if that's unexpected; it's not clear from your post how it's being assigned.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
With your help I found the origin of the error: I use excel tables. When the page is not protected and when I make changes to the cell (`target`) first the excel table automatically adds a new row to itself, a change event is triggered, so intersect works (`rgRecName` is set as `DataBodyRange` ), but when the page is protected , the vba event will works first, a new row will not be added to the table, so intersect will become nothing. However, I still haven't figured out why it works in the step by (F8) variant.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Since even if the sheet is protected with the parameter `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` and `AllowInsertingRows:=True` the excel table itself will not be able to automatically add a new row below the last one, for me I had three working solutions:

1. Use the `intersect` method with `EntireColumn` instead  `DataBodyRange` range.
2. Use a table to which a row has already been added with the `ListObject.ListRows.Add` method, each time you fill a value to last row, a new empty row is added. In this case, you can continue to use the `intersect` method with the `DataBodyRange` range.
3. Since the worksheet does not have a before change event, the `Worksheet.SelectionChange` event can be used in the work area, so while waiting for the entered data, the protection is already removed in time, allowing the excel table to automatically add a row. Changing the selection to any other cell will protect the page.